# UITextField delegate method not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am presenting an alert with UITextfield, but its delegate methods are not getting called. What wrong I might be doing.  I am using the below code to show the alert with textfield.

```
  func takePasscodeToEnableTouch(){
   self.passcodeInputOperationType = .EnableTouchID

   alertControllerPassCodeEntry = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Enter Passcode to enable the Touch Id.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
    }
    alertControllerPassCodeEntry!.addAction(cancelAction)

    alertControllerPassCodeEntry!.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (txtField) -> Void in
        txtField.placeholder = "Enter passcode"
        txtField.delegate = self
        txtField.tag = TextFieldTag.EnterPassCode
        txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation
        txtField.accessibilityIdentifier = "PassCode"
        txtField.secureTextEntry = true
        txtField.addTarget(self, action:"textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    }

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertControllerPassCodeEntry!, animated: true, completion: nil )
}
```

And the textField delegate methods are :

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) // became first responder
{

}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
{

}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    var isLimitExist: Bool
    var accessIndentifier: String
    if let str = textField.accessibilityIdentifier
    {
        accessIndentifier = str
    }
    else
    {
        accessIndentifier = ""
    }

    //checkFieldLimit function is used to check the limit of text and restrict
    isLimitExist = UIUtils.checkFieldLimit(accessIndentifier, stringToMatch: textField.text!, rangeLength: range.length, stringLength: string.characters.count)

    if !isLimitExist
    {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Where are the text field delegate methods? Update your question with the delegate methods that are not being called.

Comment: And why do you have all of those `!` in your code?

Comment: I am keeping the reference of alert controller. and I made it optional.

Comment: Are all of those text field delegate methods in the same class as the alert controller? Are those methods at the top level of the class (in other words, not inside some other method)?

Comment: What is `self` in this context? Since you show the alert from `rootViewController`, does `self` exist (`delegate`s are usually `weak`) after showing the alert ?

Comment: I am using a class for that. class PasscodeManager : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate  { ..... }

Comment: Where `txtField` was inited?

Comment: UIAlertcontroller has method addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler using that you can show the textfield in UIAlertController.

Comment: @manageinvite : do you retain your `PasscodeManager` anywhere? Is it a singleton? Show us how you create it and where you call `takePasscodeToEnableTouch`.

Comment: That method is getting called from another controller.    @IBAction func swtchTouchAction(sender: UISwitch)
    {
        if sender.on
        {
           let passCodeManager  = PasscodeManager()
           passCodeManager.delegate = self
           passCodeManager.takePasscodeToEnableTouch()
        }
        else
        {
            let passCodeManager  =  PasscodeManager()
            passCodeManager.delegate = self
            passCodeManager.authenticatePasscodeToDisalbeTouch()
        }
    }

Comment: Please do not rollback significant edits made by other users. Any content on Stack Overflow belongs to the community as a whole. If the edit made is harmful to the post itself, then a rollback is justified. I've locked the post for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so with information from the comments, everything seems clear now. To recap, you call the method showing the alert like this :

```
@IBAction func swtchTouchAction(sender: UISwitch) { 
    if sender.on { 
        let passCodeManager = PasscodeManager() 
        passCodeManager.delegate = self 
        passCodeManager.takePasscodeToEnableTouch() 
    } else { 
        let passCodeManager = PasscodeManager() 
        passCodeManager.delegate = self
        passCodeManager.authenticatePasscodeToDisalbeTouch() 
    } 
}
```

Now, you don't retain (meaning - assign to a strong property) the `passCodeManager` anywhere in here. This means, that at the end of this method this object gets destroyed (thanks to `ARC - Automatic Reference Counting`). One may think that it would get retained because you assigned it as a `delegate` of the text field, but delegates are `weak` proeprties 99.99% of time - this means that they don't bump the retain count of objects assigned to them.

To solve your immediate issue you should make a property in your class in which you have `swtchTouchAction` method and change your code like this :

```
var passCodeManager: PasscodeManager?

@IBAction func swtchTouchAction(sender: UISwitch) { 
    if sender.on { 
        self.passCodeManager = PasscodeManager() 
        self.passCodeManager?.delegate = self 
        self.passCodeManager?.takePasscodeToEnableTouch() 
    } else { 
        self.passCodeManager = PasscodeManager() 
        self.passCodeManager?.delegate = self
        self.passCodeManager?.authenticatePasscodeToDisalbeTouch() 
    } 
}
```

This will be enough to retain your passcode manager.

I'd also suggest you read up on how [memory management is done in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

Comment: Thank you so much  Losiowaty.